# Batch File to Copy and Rename SQL Backup File created Today

Tags: batch-file, copy, rename, database-backups

I am currently working on a batch file to delete the previous file, copy any file created "Today" and rename to a generic name. This is for Restoring a DB file on a daily basis from the backup file that has been created today from another instance.

```
@echo off

echo deleting previous file.....

del E:\DataRestore\DBRestore.bak /f

FOR /F %%I IN ('dir /B /O:D *.bak') DO SET filename=%%I

FOR %%f IN (%filename%) DO SET temp=%%~tf

set mydate=%temp:~6,4%%temp:~0,2%%temp:~3,2%

FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%I IN ('DATE /t') DO SET mydate2=%%L%%J%%K 

ECHO last modified file date is %mydate%

if %mydate2%==%mydate% 

RENAME %%I DBRestore.bak

DO COPY %%I E:\DataRestore & exit /b
```

I am getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if %mydate2%==%mydate%

RENAME %%I DBRestore.bak

DO COPY %%I E:\DataRestore & exit /b
```

The above lines are not valid batch syntax.

1. You cannot have an `if` with a condition, but no action.
2. You cannot use loop variables (`%%I`) outside a loop.
3. `do` is only a valid keyword in `for` loops.

Also, you don't need to determine the current date via `date /t`. There's a variable `%DATE%` providing that information.

Your script should probably look somewhat like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo deleting previous file.....
del E:\DataRestore\DBRestore.bak /f

set mydate2=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%

for /F %%I in ('dir /B /O:D *.bak') do (
  set "filename=%%~fI"

  set "temp=%%~tI"
  set "mydate=!temp:~6,4!!temp:~0,2!!temp:~3,2!"

  echo last modified file date is !mydate!

  if "%mydate2%"=="!mydate!" (
    copy "!filename!" E:\DataRestore\DBRestore.bak
    exit /b
  )
)
```